# On jquery fadeIn, how can i make it such that they will stay on the same line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So im trying to have 2 pieces of text stay on the same line when i fade them in *and* have it so that they wont jump when they do fade in. At one point i got them on the same line (I have no clue what i did) but they jumped when they faded in. Now they are on different lines and i have no idea how to fix it. I'm fairly certain that i need to mess with the

```
'display'
```

node to get it do work. But the display and positioning is my weakpoint as i am fairly new.

Below is a link to a fiddle  of what i have thus far. If anyone can help and possibly explain it to me, i would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/sKbzL/5/

When you look at the jFiddle, hit run then scroll down on the 'result' tab

Comment: I don't see nothing happening?

Comment: You're jsfiddle not working.

Comment: Try out the new link, when you hit run, scroll down a bit or expand the window upwards and you'll see the text fade in.

Comment: Consider using absolute positioning, and then fading things in over each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions,

1- you can remove the `<div>` tags surrounding the `<P>` as in this example
http://jsfiddle.net/sKbzL/4/

2- you can add `float: left;` attribute to the class .futuresurround as in this example
http://jsfiddle.net/sKbzL/7/

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if I'm mistaken, but you don't want the element to jump when it shows right ?

Then ues opacity instead of hide and animate the opacity.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#future').css('opacity',0);
    $('#dev').css('opacity',0).animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 3000);

    $('#future').delay(2000).animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 2000)

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sKbzL/8/)

Comment: This solution is exactly what i needed. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#dev').css('display', 'none').fadeIn(2000);
$('#future').css('display', 'none').fadeIn(3000);
```

This should hide the 2 p elements initially, then apply the fading in to them.

--- UPDATE ---

Actually `display: none` is exactly what `hide()` does. However after doing some amendments to your fiddle it seems that it seems to be working:

http://jsfiddle.net/kL9u8/

I removed the big black top banner, so that I actually could see what I was doing :)